# Cmake trouble with python on windows

Tags: python, c++, windows, cmake, python-3.4

I tried to build C++ project using cmake on Windows. But I catch an error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageH
andleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES) (found suitable
  version "3.4.1", minimum required is "3.4")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandard
Args.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:205
(FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

I.e., cmake could not find `PYTHON_LIBRARIES` target. But Python 3.4.1 is installed on my PC. My OS is Windows 7 preofessional x64. If I build this project on Linux, it works fine.

**Where is a problem? How can I help cmake to find `PYTHON_LIBRARIES`?**

Here is my `CMakeLists` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILES on)
project(Proj)
set(SOURCE_FILES repeating_count.cpp)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.4.1)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.4 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
python_add_module(repeating_count repeating_count.cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
add_executable(Proj ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Proj ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my issue. My default Cmake generator is Visual Studio 12 2013.

So, if I change it to Visual Studio 12 2013 **Win64** (using Cmake GUI for example), it finds `PYTHON_LIBRARIES` target and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
find_package(PythonLibs 3.4.1 EXACT REQUIRED)
```

instead of

```
find_package(PythonLibs 3.4 REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. To build project using cmake, I changed default generator to Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64 (in Cmake GUI). Then, how I can **make** resulting cmake files into .dll file? I tried GnuWin32 and MinGW, but they can't build Visual Studio files.

Comment: @VelKerr I'm not sure. Do you mean that you solved the issue changing the default generator to Visual Studio 12 2013?

Comment: yes. But I have to note: Visual Studio 12 2013 **Win64** is necessary. If you choose simply Visual Studio 12 2013, you will catch an error.

Comment: @VeLKerr Great :) Maybe you should post your own solution and mark it as the right one.

Comment: ok. But now I have many VS-files and don't know how to build `.dll` (or `.so`) from them for further using C++ code in Python. Can you help me?

Comment: @VeLKerr I'm good in cmake, but unfortunately not in Visual Studio. Could you please post a new question in SO?